# Moving drone 3d Object using Spark AR framework

Tags: macos, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to rotate, scale or move Drone 3D fbx object in Spark AR.
But unable to join the patches in correct sequence .
Please help,as i am a beginner in the AR domain.

I have attached the screenshots for reference.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open this sample project, and change 3d model to yours.

[image]

Comment: Also, please suggest me easy way to proceed with simple logic .. because the logic of patch looks complicated to me.

Comment: @AllTech just delete patches step by step until you will end up with only things you need!